# why changed all my file dates after changing a branch

Tags: git

After `git checkout my_branch` all file dates are changed.

Is it *possible* to avoid it?
Im working under windows.

Comment: `git checkout` should only touch files that are different between your previous `HEAD` and the new branch. How different was your branch to your previous state?

Comment: Very different. `git checkout` sets all file timestamps to the current time.

Comment: So if the branches are very different, how many files are identical between the two branches and have you confirmed that git (not something else) has definitely touched these files?

Comment: `git checkout my_branch` changes all file timestamps to the current date/time for files which are not identical. Is it possible to avoid?

Comment: No. That is expected and correct behaviour. Out of curiosity, why would wouldn't you want the files to have the correct timestamp (when they were last changed - the time of the checkout action)?

Comment: Because this is the current date, not the time when the file is edited.

Comment: I don't think I really understand what timestamp you want your files to have. When you switch branches files in the working tree have to be updated so their timestamp should reflect when they were updated, surely?

Answer (score 0):

When you added your files to git via `git add` you've taken a snapshot of them at this moment. So when you `git checkout` another commit (or branch) you will get these snapshots of your files. Its not possible to avoid it.